# Floor function sum identity

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Prove, that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}  \left \lfloor{\frac{x}{2^{n}}+\frac{1}{2}}\right \rfloor =\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor  $$ for large enough N.

It's easy to see that addents start to vanish at some point (it's possible to calculate for which n it takes place). But I can't say much more about this proof so any help would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=-3.5$. Then we have

$$\sum_{n\ge 1}\left\lfloor\frac{-3.5}{2^n}+\frac12\right\rfloor=\lfloor-1.25\rfloor+\lfloor-0.375\rfloor+\lfloor0.0625\rfloor+\ldots=-2-1=-3\;,$$

but $\lfloor-3.5\rfloor=-4$. The result is clearly true for $x=0$, so I will assume that that $x>0$. Let $b_mb_{m-1}\ldots b_0.d_1d_2\ldots$ be the binary representation of $x$, so that

$$x=\sum_{k=0}^mb_k2^k+\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{d_k}{2^k}\;.$$

For $n\ge 1$ let

$$x_n=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2^n}+\frac12\right\rfloor\;;$$

then for $1\le n\le m$ we have $x_n=(b_m\ldots b_n)_{\text{two}}+b_{n-1}$, $x_{m+1}=b_m=1$, and $x_n=0$ for $n>m+1$. Thus, if $\beta(x)$ is the number of $1$ bits in the binary representation of $\lfloor x\rfloor$,

$$\sum_{n\ge 1}x_n=\sum_{n\ge 1}\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2^n}\right\rfloor+\beta(x)\;.$$

The binary representations of the terms $\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2^n}\right\rfloor$ for $1\le n\le m$ are shown in the following table.

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
n&&&\;\;\lfloor x/2^n\rfloor\\ \hline
1&b_m&b_{m-1}&b_{m-2}&\ldots&b_2&b_1\\
2&&b_m&b_{m-1}&\ldots&b_3&b_2\\
3&&&b_m&\ldots&b_4&b_3\\
&&&&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
m-1&&&&&b_m&b_{m-1}\\
m&&&&&&b_m
\end{array}$$

Note that for $k=1\ldots,m$, $b_k$ appears in the first $k$ rows, once in each of the rightmost $k$ positions, so it contributes altogether

$$b_k\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}2^i=\begin{cases}
2^k-1,&\text{if }b_k=1\\
0,&\text{if }b_k=0\;.
\end{cases}$$

to $\sum_{n\ge 1}\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2^n}\right\rfloor$. There are $\beta(x)-b_0$ values of $k\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ such that $b_k=1$, so

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\ge 1}x_n&=\sum_{n\ge 1}\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2^n}\right\rfloor+\beta(x)\\\\
&=\sum_{\substack{1\le k\le m\\b_k=1}}\left(2^k-1\right)+\beta(x)\\\\
&=\sum_{\substack{1\le k\le m\\b_k=1}}2^k-\big(\beta(x)-b_0\big)+\beta(x)\\\\
&=(\lfloor x\rfloor-b_0)+b_0\\\\
&=\lfloor x\rfloor\;,
\end{align*}$$

as desired.

Comment: First: user EmEl put  his comment "Fourth is not zero term" before my already written "You are wrong, dear friend" so I did not put my comment.
Second: You work (with better English  and better TeX Commands, of course) with the binary representation of $x$ before I finish the same way. (This happen to me many times in StackExchange). My respects.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is too late to add an answer, however, it is a well-known identity that 
$$\left\lfloor u+ \frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor u \right\rfloor =\left \lfloor 2u\right \rfloor$$ for every $u\in \mathbb{R}$. Putting $u = \frac{x}{2^n}$, by the above identity we obtain 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \left \lfloor  \frac{x}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor=\sum_{n=1}^{N} (\left\lfloor   \frac{x}{2^{n-1}}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor   \frac{x}{2^{n}}\right\rfloor )$$
which is a telescopic series and is then equal to 
$$\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \frac{x}{2^N}\right \rfloor $$
for every $N\geq 1$. This also generalizes the identity mentioned in the OP as if we choose $N$ large enough,  $\left\lfloor \frac{x}{2^N} \right\rfloor=0$ for $x>0$. If $x<0$, then the RHS would be $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor +1$ which also justifies the example given by Brian M. Scott.

Comment: Yes exactly! +1. This is the simplest way, wonder why it wasn't written before ;)

Answer (score 1):

A quick check you can do is when some term $\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$ in the left side increases.  You should find that it increases exactly when $x$ becomes $2^{n-1}$ times an odd number.  So when $x$ increases between integers, the left side doesn't increase at all and obviously neither does the right.

But when $x$ becomes an integer, there is a unique maximal power of $2$ that it is divisible by, and this term and this term alone increases.  For example, if $x$ goes from $2.9$ to $3$, the term $\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$ increases from $1$ to $2$, and none of the other terms increase.  And if $x$ goes from $7.9$ to $8$, the term $\left\lfloor\frac{x}{16}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$ increases from $0$ to $1$ and no other term on the left increases at all.

So if at integers the left increases by 1 and nowhere else, this is exactly what the right is, since both are $0$ at $x=0$.  So the left and right sides must be equal.

Comment: Thank you, very nice solution.